# monodroid wcf call

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android

I'm having difficulties with accessing a WCF service.  My service is
running in the same solution as the MonoDroid App and is hosted by visual
studio. I configured it as BasicHttp. The reference adds ok but at runtime
when I call the one simple test method, I get ;

System.Net.WebException
it's very simple this is web service

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and here is call

```
        button.Click += delegate
        { 
       localhost.Service1 se = new localhost.Service1();
        button.Text= se.HelloWorld();
        };
```

and error snapshot in attachment

[image: error]

Comment: I think you will need to add much more detail before anyone can really help. e.g. try adding some code showing how you are configuring your client and try adding some more detail about the contents of the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that you need to add more information.  However, I responded to this question sometime ago and this is what I am doing for the WCF stuff and it's working great for me.

[Using Soap in Shared Mono Library for WP 7 and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332967/using-soap-in-shared-mono-library-for-wp-7-and-android/10435061#10435061)

This might help out.

One other thing that I just thought of.   Do you have the internet option in the network manifest selected as shown here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/1026/=RequiredPermissionsVS.png